# sqlalchemy: distinct only on one column

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

My table looks like this:

```
    title      |    slug
------------------------------
The Title      | the-title
Another Title  | another-title
another title  | another-title
```

I want to select by distinct slug, but also want the title returned as part of the results. Which title gets returned for multiple matches, I don't care.

So my results look like this:

```
[('The Title', 'the-title'), ('Another Title', 'another-title')]
```

Comment: Did you mean 'another-slug' instead of 'another-title' in your example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to do something like:

```
session.query(func.max(Table.title), Table.slug).group_by(Table.slug).all()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also solve this with:

```
session.query(Table.title, Table.slug).distinct(Table.slug)
```

This also allows you to return additional fields (say you wanted to see `Table.id`) in the same `.query()` field list, without requiring a separate subquery.

Comment: With the current sqlalchemy version I get `SADeprecationWarning: DISTINCT ON is currently supported only by the PostgreSQL dialect.  Use of DISTINCT ON for other backends is currently silently ignored, however this usage is deprecated, and will raise CompileError in a future release for all backends that do not support this syntax.`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a `distinct` keyword, you should use an `aggregate` function with a `group by` clause. Consider the following SQL to solve your need:

```
SELECT MAX(title), slug
  FROM yourtable
GROUP BY slug
```

The `group by` clause will cause the query to return only one row per distinct value for slug. The `max` function is an aggregate function which will return the maximum value for title within each group. This will give you one of the titles and since you don't care which one, that should be all you need.